# Extracting Substrings from textboxes in VB

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a VB program for school. I am having some trouble extracting a substring from a string and I would really appreciate some help.

The form has different text boxes and one of them is where you type in a person's full name into one text box. The listbox on the form, when hitting the compute button, is supposed to display only the person's last name.

I am not sure how I am supposed to extract just the last name of the string of whatever name is typed into the text box.

All I got so far is:

```
Dim name As String

name = txtName.Text
```

(txtName is the name of the text box)

Okay, so I added:

```
lstOut.Items.Add(name.Substring(6))
```

That to my code. The name I typed in for an example when I ran the program was Helen Woods. 6 is in the substring because that is where the space starts and when I clicked compute, it listed only the last name, just like I wanted. But, this only works if the first name is five letters long. I need a way to make the program automatically find the space in between the two names.

EDIT:

When I add:

```
lstOut.Items.Add(name.IndexOf(""))
```

The listbox gives me a 0 whenever I type in a name and hit the compute button.

Comment: If you're reasonable sure that first and last name are separated by space - look into String.Split function

Comment: Take a look at the [Substring](http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-vbnet) function. Also take a look at [IndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexof-vbnet) and [LastIndexOf](http://www.dotnetperls.com/lastindexof-vbnet)

Comment: I used the substring method and it kind of worked, but only if I had the position of the space between the first and last name. And the position of the space depends on how long the name is. I need it to work with any length names.

Comment: Please update your code with what you tried.

Comment: You were on the right track. Now instead of number `6` try `name.IndexOf(" ")`

Comment: You wrote `name.IndexOf("")`. That’s an empty string, and there’s one at the start of every string. Try a space instead: `name.IndexOf(" ")`. And add one to that.

Comment: And keep using Substring. Here's exact line, just try copy/paste it:  `stOut.Items.Add(name.Substring(name.IndexOf(" ")))`

Comment: I used the exact line Yuriy Galanter gave me and it worked! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Private Sub GetLastName()
  dim lsName as new List(Of String)
  dim name as string
  for each name in txtName.text.split(" ")
    lsName.Add(name)
  next
  lstOut.items.Add(lsName.item(lsName.count-1))
end sub
```

You can call this procedure at your button event.